# How to call a function with parameters from another function that has parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Im using [D3](http://d3js.org/) and JS.

I have a function that creates buttons and one of the parameters is `onClick` which runs when the buttons is clicked (obviously).

For example:

```
simpleButton(imageURL, width, height, title, onClick){
.attr("xlink:href", imageUrl) //-original image
    .attr( "width", width) //-icon width
    .attr( "height", height) //-icon height
    .on("click", onClick)
    .append("svg:title")
    .text(title); //-give the button a title
}
```

Now one of my buttons I'm going to use to hide some shapes (i.e. set `visibility:hidden`).

So I have created another function to hide the selection, something like:

```
hideSelection(selection){
    selection.classed("hidden", true);
}
```

This function takes on one parameter so that I can pass through what I want to hide.

So for example what I thought would work looks like this:

```
simpleButton("\images\dog", 100, 100, "dog", hideSelection(dog));
```

Now, this does work, but it works straight away without me clicking. I know it's because I'm calling the `hideSelection` straight away because of the parenthesis-().

But my question is, how do I stop calling this function straight away when running it ? How do I run a function with parameters via another function that has parameters (if that makes any sense at all)?

Comment: ah I didn't know, but now I do :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
simpleButton("\images\dog",100,100, "dog", function() {
  hideSelection(dog)
});
```

This function has access to the `dog` variable because it's a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) - a function that has access to the parent scope at the time it was created.

Comment: closures !! was reading about that last week, totally forgot. Thank you, all working perfectly :)) Ill choose this as the answer once it lets me

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed calling `hideSelection(dog)` immediately and passing the *result* of that to `simpleButton` - you need to pass a *reference* to a function. The easiest way to do that is to wrap it in another function:

```
simpleButton("\\images\\dog", 100, 100, "dog", function() {
    hideSelection(dog)
});
```

(P.S.You probably want to escape the `\`s in the image path too)

Comment: @joews beat you to it im afraid :L thank you though, understand it now :) and the link to the image was just an example, thanks again :)